# How to show pdf content in Laravel 5?

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

I have this view :

```
@extends('template')

@section('main')
<div class="container singlefullwidth sitecontainer single-wrapper bgw">
    <div class="row">
        <div class="col-md-10 col-md-offset-1 m22 single-post">
            <div class="widget">
                <div class="large-widget m30">
                    <div class="post-desc">
                        <h2 style="text-align: center;">{{ $jurnal->judul }}</h2>
                        <p style="text-align: center;"><strong>{{ $jurnal->penulis }}</strong></p>
                        <p style="text-align: center;"><strong>Abstrak :</strong></p>
                        <p>{{ $jurnal->abstrak }}</p>
                        <p style="text-align: center;"><a href="{{ asset('pdfupload/' . $jurnal->file) }}" style="color : #00569d;">View Journal</a></p>
                    </div><!-- end post-desc -->
                </div><!-- end large-widget -->
            </div><!-- end widget -->
        </div><!-- end col -->
    </div><!-- end row -->
</div><!-- end container -->
@stop
```

I wanted visitor will be able to view the pdf file in browser when they click "View Journal". How to make this possible in Laravel ? thank you

Answer (score 0):

Depending on where the pdf is stored (in the public folder or the asset folder which isnt assible to the user). 
A) You could setup a route that returns a file response to the user. https://laravel.com/docs/5.3/responses#file-responses or
B) You can have a pdf folder located in the public folder that you can link to all your pdf's

Comment: the pdf file is stored in public/pdfupload